# div: всё доступное пространство с расширением

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

1. имеются view и main с height 100%. main скроллится.
2. имеются header и footer фиксированной высоты (но неизвестной заранее).
3. content скроллится и занимает всё свободное место (например, при увеличении header, он уменьшается).
4. Однако уменьшаться он может до заданной высоты, после чего начинает расширяться блок view.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как такое можно получить? Попробовал через flex.
Дело в том что при height 100% блока view при расширении он начинает залазить на другой блок из за жёсткого заданного height (т.е происходит overflow). А заданный height у view не уберешь, т.к. невозможно реализовать пункт 3.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="view">
        <div class="header"></div>
         <div class="content"></div>
          <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="view">
        <div class="header"></div>
         <div class="content"></div>
          <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.main {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.view {
    height: 100%;
}

.header, .footer {
    height: 30px;
}

.content {
    overflow: auto;
//    height: all remaining space until min-height
    min-height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Не понял `Однако уменьшаться он может до заданной высоты, после чего начинает расширяться блок view` Это как? Внутренности уменьшаются, а оболочка при этом увеличивается?

Comment: @Sergey Допустим, мы увеличиваем блок header, при этом блок content (так как ему положено только доступное свободное место) уменьшается, чтобы заполнить всё родительское место. Таким путём header можно увеличивать дальше, в один момент content исчезнет вовсе. Вот тут и хотелось сделать так, что бы content имел min-height, после которого он бы перестал уменьшаться, а стал увеличиваться блок view.